# Allennlp german elmo model

Tags: python, elmo, allennlp

I want to build a Q&A bot with allennlp. I already found the code for it and an English model - I want to use the bot with german. I already searched for it, but I only found [this](https://github.com/t-systems-on-site-services-gmbh/german-elmo-model) model which is unfortunately not compatible with allennlp. Do you know about any compatible german elmo models, or is there a more common alternative to allennlp which has more compatible models?

This is the code I found:

```
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor
import allennlp_models.rc

predictor = Predictor.from_path("https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/bidaf-elmo-model-2020.03.19.tar.gz")

result = predictor.predict(
  passage="Steve Jobs died in 2011. He was born in 1955. He has multiple children.",
  question="When did Steve Jobs die?"
)
print(result['best_span_str'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I found out that TensorFlow offers a [multilingual sentence encoder](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-qa/1) which can be used for Questions Answering as well. Training my own Elmo model was not an option as it is too computationally expensive.